# Azure Functions using App Service Plan: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I have problem connecting remote FTP server using certificates on Azure Functions using App Service Plan, got the exception below:

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure. System.Exception
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException

Below is my **setup on Azure Functions**

1.Two public certificates have been uploaded to Azure Functions like below by following the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-ssl-cert-load
[image]
Please note the location above, `App Service Plan` is used, so should it be `LocalMachine\My`?

> This setting places the specified certificates in the Current User\My
>   store for most pricing tiers, but in the Isolated tier (i.e. app runs
>   in an App Service Environment), it places the certificates in the
>   Local Machine\My store.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-ssl-cert-load

2.The code below is also used to load the certificate on Azure Functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-ssl-cert-load#load-the-certificate-in-code

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                            X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                            // Replace below with your certificate's thumbprint
                            "E661583E8FABEF4C0BEF694CBC41C28FB81CD870",
                            false);
// Get the first cert with the thumbprint
if (certCollection.Count > 0)
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
    // Use certificate
    Console.WriteLine(cert.FriendlyName);
}
certStore.Close();
```

Below is my **setup locally**

It has no problem connecting to remote FTP server on my local machine using the code below, in combination of the two certificate setup on my local machine below

```
 private X509Certificate2 GetX509Certificate2FromFile()
    {
        return new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine("myCert.cer"));
    }
```

**Root CA certificate** is installed under `Trusted Root Certificate Authorities` folder

**Issuing CA certificate** installed under `Intermediate Certificated Authorities` folder

**Update**
Detailed exception can be found https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d1db13e9ee7143cf98653b807cfad75b

Comment: Can you share the error codes you are seeing and exception text when running in your app service plan?

Comment: Please see the exception on Update section.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be that an issue with FTPs server cert is not trusted by client.  I believe you may be talking about an App Service Environment (Isolated).  If you are using the version of ILB ASE that supports your own custom domain they need to load the cert using WEBSITE_LOAD_ROOT_CERTIFICATES if the cert being used isn’t from a trusted CA.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/certificates#private-client-certificate

Comment: I am using App Service Plan, not App Service Environment, which is, if I am correct, available for `Isolated` host. But I think I am not using it. It is confusing.

Comment: @Pingpong, the isolated SKU means you are using an ASE. See the link below for more context. 
Link for pricing : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/

As you mentioned on your local machine you are loading the certificate into the trusted root. You'll need to follow the same steps for apps. 

Blog on loading certs into the trusted root: https://blog.brooksjc.com/2019/07/05/load-root-certificate-in-an-ilb-ase/